# Call a separate class in other pages?

Tags: c#

I have two files. One is Scenario2_Client.Xaml.cs and other is test.cs. I want to call an EchoClient class inside one of the method in Scenario2_Client.Xaml.cs.

In test.cs I have this code:

```
public class EchoClient
    public static void Main() {     
        try { 
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("139.169.63.130", 9999);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            string s = string.Empty;
            while(!s.Equals("Exit")) {

                Console.WriteLine("TCP Client connected....");
                Console.Write("Enter a string or number to send to the server: ");
                s = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                writer.WriteLine(s);
                writer.Flush();
                string server_string = reader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(server_string);
            }

            reader.Close();
            writer.Close();
            client.Close();

        } catch(Exception e) { 

            Console.WriteLine(e);               
        }
    }
}
```

And on Scenario2_Client.Xaml.cs has this:

```
public sealed partial class Scenario2_Client : Page
{ 
    // code
    // code

    private void RemoveValueChangedHandler() // this is where I want to add EchoClient class
    {  
        ValueChangedSubscribeToggle.Content = "Subscribe to value changes";
        if (subscribedForNotifications)
        {
            registeredCharacteristic.ValueChanged -= Characteristic_ValueChanged;
            registeredCharacteristic = null;
            subscribedForNotifications = false;
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly here are some steps I would recommend:

- Split your main method out into a new class. A runner class or something like that.
- Create a new class called EchoClient and add the methods that it implements.
- You can then call that class from the Scenario class.

Before you do those steps it might be worth checking out some tutorials on how to create classes and what they represent. There are many good resources out there. 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mkagrahari/introduction-to-object-oriented-programming-concepts-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Tried it. Created an instance: EchoClient echoclient = new EchoClient() And also I also created new class EchoClient but still not working.